# Adicionar row em jquery com SessionStorage

Tags: jquery, html5

boa tarde
estou tentando fazer uma especie de formulario onde salvo alguns valores usando sessionStorage e ao retornar o codigo, pretendo exibir os valores em uma tabela html, porem os numeros nao mostram em uma sequencia exata, alguem já teve esse problema?
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

HTML:

```
<form>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label>ID:</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="idDigitado" placeholder="id" disabled>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Valor:</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="valorDigitado" placeholder="valor" required>
    </div>

    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="botaoSalva">Salvar</button>

    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="exibeTabela">Exibir Tabela</button>

</form>


<div class="table-responsive">
    <table class="table table-striped tabela">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>#</th>
                <th>Header</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody id="corpo">
            <tr id="conteudoTabela">
                <td>asf</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var idDigitado = 0;
    var valorDigitado = 0;
    var indiceGeral = sessionStorage.length + 1;
    $("#idDigitado").val(indiceGeral);
    $("#botaoSalva").click(function() {
        pegaCampos();
    });

    function pegaCampos() {
        idDigitado = $("#idDigitado").val();
        valorDigitado = $("#valorDigitado").val();
        $("#alerta").text(idDigitado + "-" + valorDigitado);

        salva();
    }

    function salva() {
        sessionStorage.setItem(idDigitado, valorDigitado);
        //atualizaTabela();
        atualizaIndice();
    }

    /*
    function atualizaTabela(){
        for(var i=0; i < sessionStorage.length; i++){
            var indice = sessionStorage.key(i);
            $("table").append("<tr><td>"+sessionStorage.key(i)+"</td><td>"+sessionStorage.getItem(indice)+"</td></tr>");
        }
    }
    */

    function atualizaIndice() {
        var indiceGeral = sessionStorage.length + 1;
        $("#idDigitado").val(indiceGeral);
    }

    $("#exibeTabela").click(function() {
        //$(".table").append("<tr><td>"+sessionStorage.key(i)+"</td><td>"+sessionStorage.getItem(indice)+"</td></tr>");
        var quantidadeGravada = sessionStorage.length;
        for (var i = 0; i <= quantidadeGravada; i += 1) {
            var indice = sessionStorage.key(i);
            var linha = "<tr><td>" + indice + "</td></tr>";
            $(".tabela").append(linha);

            var quantidadeLinhas = $(".tabela tbody tr").length;
            console.log(quantidadeLinhas);
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

O único problema é que você estava usando como indice o

```
var indice = sessionStorage.key(i);
```

mas como voce controla o indice sequencial na mão, você pode usar somente o valor da variável i

```
var indice = i;
```

Criei um fiddle pra testar, acho que está funcionando como esperado: [Session storage resolvido no fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/r7mbxemz/)

Outro problema que resolvi no fiddle mas que não estava na pergunta é que você estava partindo o for de zero, o que te traz valores "undefined" tem que ser de 1 até o sessionStorage.lenght (ta corrigido no fiddle também)

Comment: cara, muito obrigado! finalmente vou poder dar continuidade ao meu projeto \o/

Comment: Que bom que ajudou :). Por favor lembre de marcar a resposta como correta e dar um UP ali hehehe